# How to call base class copy constructor from a derived class copy constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, copy-constructor

Just like in the title, how do you call a base class copy constructor from a derived class copy constructor?

Comment: The more important Q is why do you want to do this?

Comment: @AlokSave obviously, to get their code to compile and come out with their app, they need to do this.  Duh

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can specify base initialization in the initialization list:

```
Derived:: Derived( const Derived& other ): Base( other )
{ /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 11):

```
Derived( Derived const& d )
: Base(d)
/* some member initialization */
{
  /* ... */
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Don't get smaht.